# Xcode NSData Image Size Change

Tags: xcode, width, nsdata, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I want to save an image. Therefore I convert it to a NSData.
However during these steps the width and height of the image 
will change. It is increased in size. This happens on the iPad Air
series, before the width/height remained the same.

```
NSLog(@"BEFORE %f %f",image1.size.width,image1.size.height); // Displays 200 133

// Convert to NSData
NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1,0.8f);

// Store etc.

// Convert it back
UIImage *image2=[UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];

NSLog(@"AFTER %f %f",image2.size.width,image2.size.height); // Displays 400 266
```

I do not want the imagesize to increase!

Comment: After an afternoon with frustrating searching I found that besides 'size' there is also a 'scale' for each image. This is hardly documented. For this case the scale for the image1 was set to 2. After conversion the scale value was 1. Strangely enough it is not possible to SET the scale, only read it. I had to implement a whole routine to get this fixed.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you who still want the answer to this question, as Vincent pointed out, there is a scale factor to images. Use the following code to fix it:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]  scale:1.0 orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
```